# Is there a difficulty level above insanity?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Just curious. I never finished insanity on any of the previous games. Does a new difficulty level unlock when you complete insanity?

Comment: You could always go old school NES style and only give yourself 3 continues.

By the way good luck with that... ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. Insanity is as tough as it gets.

Though I'm not sure why you'd *want* more. Insanity is pretty unforgiving as is.