# Are there multiple levels of difficulty to unlock in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difficulty level above insanity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53809/is-there-a-difficulty-level-above-insanity)

In the previous two Mass Effect games, there were higher levels of difficulty that were only available after playing through lesser difficulties. Is that the case for Mass Effect 3? If so, what are all the possible difficulties, and how do you unlock each level?

Answer (score 0):

No, Insanity is the highest difficulty and is available from the start.